# When using templates within templates in Meteor, where should events be called?

Tags: meteor

I have various different views for my Books collection, which results in a general template "books" but also many smaller templates within "books". For example, "bookCovers", "bookList", "bookSearch".

I seem to have most events working OK but feel like I'm getting into a real mess with my code in terms of on which event a certain function should be called.

I started off trying to store as many in the outermost template as possible (so I would only have to call them once) but some events wouldn't run seemingly without calling them on the "inner" template.

I'm also a little unsure if there is a best practice for keeping my files nice and tidy - one file for each inner template or try and keep as much called on the outer template as possible?

Apologies if this question isn't very precise but I feel it's an area that isn't terribly well covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @blackcat and typically define events on the lowest level template. That allows me to change it without worrying about the impact on templates above it. More importantly, in `{{#each}}` and `{{#with}}` blocks you get the right data context in `this`.

While Meteor has *global helpers*, it doesn't have *gloval events*. This does make it harder to modularize code.

A couple approaches to that include:

1. Defining global functions that the individual event handlers call to keep code DRY.
2. Using *dynamic templates* where the event is defined on the parent template but the inner template is selected dynamically.

Comment: Thank you @michel-floyd for another great answer. I'm going to try deferring some of my events to global functions as I'm calling them twice in some cases (book list view / book covers view)

Answer (score 1):

From my humble experience, it's better to have a "component" approach. I try to keep my templates as tiny and simple as possible (split them when they become too big). I define my events on the lowest level possible, meaning from the actual template that produces the DOM from where the event is fired, not from a parent template.

I do this for two reasons:

- You have reusable components
- The code is very much easier to read

I find the [recommendations for angular architecture](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) quite relevant, and often try to stick with this.

In a nutshell: one file for each template, one js file for each template with the related logic, and one scss file for each too.

Still I would very much like to hear other people minds on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Blackcat. Bit unsure as whether to mark as accepted as like you am also interested in other views!

Comment: I tend to group related html templates into a single file as otherwise I end up with all these 5 line files running around. When template A nests template B which nests template C it's easier to see them and edit them right next to each other. I think that's just personal preference though.